# Error while setting up facebook android sdk v4 in eclipse using gradle

Tags: android, eclipse, libgdx, android-gradle-plugin, facebook-android-sdk

I have been trying to get the facebook sdk v4 to work with my existing libgdx android project. Here are the steps i took:
¹. Imported facebook android sdk v4 as gradle project to my workspace. Went well

2. Edited my android projects properties to include facebook sdk as library. Didnt work,couldnt import classes
3. Reverted 2nd step and added project to java build path. Didnt work
4. Added individual jar files as dependencues. Worked but not all classes could be imported maybe the one that were not included in jar?

Now I am totally confused as most of the topics online refer to older sdk.Please guide me

Answer (score 0):

You can update your libgdx project to Gradle using https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Project-Setup-Gradle. Then you can add a dependency to the facebook-android-sdk artifact as described in 4th and 5th step here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/getting-started#androidstudio.

Comment: I already had my project on gradle from the beginning. Anyway i looked at the changelog and documentations and the classes that couldnt be imported are now deprecated in v4. I was trying to make an old code work with v4 sdk. Thank you